# DB table for weather station readings

Tags: database, database-design

I want to create a DB table to keep the sensor readings from the physical sensors (weather station). What I was thinking is to create following:

```
+--------------------------+
|         readings         |
+----+------+------+-------+
| id | type | unit | value |
+----+------+------+-------+
| 1  | 1    | 1    | 35.0  |  -- type: temperature, unit: Celsius
+----+------+------+-------+
| 2  | 1    | 2    | 145.1 |  -- type: temperature, unit: Fahrenheit
+----+------+------+-------+
```

Then I have 2 more tables to store the reading types and units:

```
+-------------------+
|   reading_types   |
+----+--------------+
| id | reading_type |
+----+--------------+
| 1  | temperature  |
+----+--------------+
| 2  | humidity     |
+----+--------------+

+--------------------------------+
|          reading_units         |
+----+--------------+------------+
| id | reading_type | unit       |
+----+--------------+------------+
| 1  | temperature  | Celsius    |
+----+--------------+------------+
| 2  | temperature  | Fahrenheit |
+----+--------------+------------+
| 3  | humidity     | Percent    |
+----+--------------+------------+
```

Would that be a good approach? How can I avoid assigning wrong unit to the reading, for example adding a record for humidity with Celsius unit? Off course it can be handled in the code, but how to make sure that data integrity will be kept? Should I create one more linking table similar to below?

```
+----------------------------------------+
|         reading_types_and_units        |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
| id | reading_type_id | reading_unit_id |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1  | 1               | 1               |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
| 2  | 1               | 2               |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
| 3  | 2               | 3               |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
| 4  | 3               | 4               |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Do temperature and humidity get recorded at the same time? They would be separate instruments, but if every time you record the temperature your also record the humidity, then why separate the data?

Comment: @GregBurghardt - I want to have possibility to keep the data from few different sensors which works indepentently. So I want to separate the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What's the problem?

Your model seems to be designed for flexibility and the possibility to configure the system easily with new devices and measurements. I suppose you simplified the details, such as the weather station, the reading device and the time stamp.

Unfortunately the DB schema has a redundancy: you have two `reading_type` that depends on different primary keys (assuming that the primary keys are the `id` columns) and nothing prevents inconsistency. You therefore need to prevent it by enforcing the inconsistency in code:

### Solution 1: let the database check the contraints

This solution stays close to your initial design.

First  **transform `reading_units`**, to make it referring directly to the `reading_type` (which defines the physical dimension) :

```
+--------------------------------+
|          reading_units         |
+----+--------------+------------+
| id | type_id      | unit       |
+----+--------------+------------+
| 1  | 1            | Celsius    |
+----+--------------+------------+
| 2  | 1            | Fahrenheit |
+----+--------------+------------+
| 3  | 2            | Percent    |
+----+--------------+------------+
```

This simplifies the constraint verification, using only keys.

Then  **transform the key definitions** to benefit from automatic database referential integrity constraints of foreign keys:

- In the modified `reading_units`,  use a **compound primary key** made of `type_id` and `id`.   This means that a unit is not defined by a simple id, but by an id and the corresponding physical dimension.
- In `readings` create a **compound foreign key constraint**  made of `type` and `unit` ([How to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34024777/3723423) on StackOverflow)

Here the DB will prevent any inconsistency with minor adaptations of your origignal model.

### Solution 2: let inconsistencies vanish

Another approach is to reengineer your design to remove completely the redundancy, so neither your code nor the database has to prevent it. This is the magic of relational database normalization.  Moreover this solution allows to keep only simple primary key.

The trick is to no longer provide redundant data in `readings`, so that there can no longer be contradiction.  The readings would then just provide the measured unit, and the unit provides the dimension (aka former `reading_type`):

```
+-------------------+
|     readings      |
+----+------+-------+
| id | unit | value |
+----+------+-------+
| 1  | 1    | 35.0  |  -- unit: Celsius, it's necessarily a temperature
+----+------+-------+
| 2  | 2    | 145.1 |  -- unit: Fahrenheit, it's necessarily a temperature
+----+------+-------+

+--------------------------------+
|               units            |
+----+--------------+------------+
| id | dimension    | unit       |
+----+--------------+------------+
| 1  | 1            | Celsius    |
+----+--------------+------------+
| 2  | 1            | Fahrenheit |
+----+--------------+------------+
| 3  | 2            | Percent    |
+----+--------------+------------+

+-------------------+
|  unit_dimensions  |
+----+--------------+
| id | dimension    |
+----+--------------+
| 1  | temperature  |
+----+--------------+
| 2  | humidity     |
+----+--------------+
```

Joining tables allows you to find back what you need whenever you need it.

Comment: Regarding "First transform reading_units, to make it referring directly to the reading_type" - I simply forgot to change it to IDs in the post. Of course it should be as you wrote.

Coming back to the topic, I think your Solution 2 is what I was looking for. I will use it in my project. Thank you!

Comment: @Kamil Thank you for your feedback. I think this is a very good choice.

Comment: To me it looks like you are trying to add a type of "System of units", but doing so in an inflexible manner.   IMHO you should first define the system of units (EG Imperial, Metric/SI, MKS etc) and the variables (Temperature, Pressure etc)  and from that the Units automatically fall out by definition (EG Imperial/Temp is °F,  Metric/Pressure is Pa etc)

Comment: @PeterM In fact, no, I don’t define a system of units: A system of units crosses dimensions (e.g. imperial: foot for length, acre for surface, gallon for volume). This would be of no use here. I just define a system of dimensions, which relates each measurement to a physical dimension, but giving full flexibility about units to be used. Here temperature could be in K, F or C. The next step would be to define for a dimension a reference unit, and a conversion factor for the other units. But this would add unnecessary complexity here, for a need that was not expressed.

Answer (score 4):

[Christophe`s answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/419243) is fine, and that kind of [EAV model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) may be perfectly justified. However, your questions provide not much context. It is perfectly possible these approaches are overdesigned. So before implementing  a design with separate tables for units and/or dimensions, ask yourself:

### Is that kind of flexibility really necessary?

A physical sensor in a weather station is nothing for which I expect to change the dimension or unit between different measured values. Probably the units do not even change over the lifetime of the instrument at all. If they do, it is a hardware change which does not happen on a daily basis, and changing the software will be required then, too.

I would also expect to get temperatures and humity values in certain time intervals, with some time stamp. So in case your goal is not to collect values from different types of weather stations in one huge database, but only the measurements from one instrument, a table design like

```
+----+--------------+------------+--------------------+
| id | Temperature  | Humidity   |Timestamp           |
+----+--------------+------------+--------------------+
|  1 | 21.5         | 95.1       | 22/11/2020 17:21:32|
|  2 | 21.1         | 95.0       | 22/11/2020 17:21:35|
...
```

makes IMHO more sense, where the units of temperature or humidity stay the same for each measurement, and the software which manages this data contains this information just hard coded. In case temperatur and humidity are measured by two separate sensors in different time intervals, one could use two tables, but following the same approach.

If one needs different units in a GUI or inside of some reporting, maybe in a configurable way, the measured values can be transformed as required. But using different units for each record where those values are stored has a certain potential to introduce more problems than it solves.

Comment: I agree with you about the temperature and the timestamp. However there are a lot of dimensions where sensors can indeed measure in different ways. Speed can be an angular speed on one sensor and a linear speed on another sensor.  Humidity can be absolute or relative, etc...   Moreover,  if this is the software controlling the wheather station as the narrative suggests, it would be better to record the different mesurement separately:  first they may be provided by the sensors at a dirrent pace.  Even if read from the sensor,  timeout could result in different timings ;-)

Comment: @Christophe: I think the main point of my answer is that the OP should check their requirements, and if they really want each record with its own unit. If there is a sensor for linear speed and one for angular speed, for example, I guess using two different columns in one table, or two different tables, could be both more useful approaches than putting those values into the same column of one table.

Comment: aha I see. So in your model the number of columns in the database depend on the number of sensors? If I understand well the consequences of your point, if tomorrow OP adds an [anemometer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemometer) to the weather station, he/she should modify the db schema. Is coupling the software to the hardware configuration really the way to go for future-proof maintainable systems?

Comment: @Christophe: this depends totally on the context, the intended life time of the hardware, the software and their coupling. My point is, the OP should reflect about their requirements, if they need to design a "future-proof, flexible software system suitable for many different sensors" (for which the kind of EAV schema they and you were talking of is fine), or if they need to design one software which fits to a fixed number of sensors. Both approaches can be "correct", it depends on the circumstances.

Comment: If you’re going to do it this way I see no reason to not simply dump it in a text log file. One for each sensor.

Comment: @candied_orange: as long as the OP does not provide any more background information, we can only speculate.

Comment: @DocBrown when you say things like that it makes me think we should close it.

Comment: @candied_orange: Christophe and me both wrote an answer showing the OP's design problem can have two different solutions, and which one is more appropriate depends on information the OP "forgot" to add to the question, or is not willing to share for whatever reason. You now added a third design suggestion, which may also make sense. That's not ideal, and it shows the question could have been written in a more specific way. However, it is IMHO not that much unspecific that it really deserves closing. But YMMV.

Comment: Hi, @Christophe and candied_orange are right. I want to have possibility to extend the system for another sensors, that's why I wanted to keep units in separate tables - to have the possibility to ad new records there in the future